# How do I distinguish the pronunciation between 'drawing' and 'join'?

Tags: pronunciation

['drɔɪŋ] [dʒɔɪn]
I really can't distinguish them.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You have indicated that the pronunciations are different. Can you give an example of a context in which drawing and join might be confused?

Comment: @JamesK /d/ and /r/ create a bit of a /ʒ/ sound when you pronounce them together. By looking at the transcriptions without hearing these words pronounced, you might come to the conclusion their pronunciations are almost indistinguishable. To the asker: listen to the pronunciations given in [this dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/) (you can click on the little speaker icons to hear them pronounced in BrE and AmE).

Comment: @JamesK, Today, after this question was asked one year, I heard this, "Levana made a grand, flourishing gesture, drawing everyone’s attention to her, though it resulted in nothing more than taking a sip of tea." Again, I misthought "drawing"  was "join." Then I searched "join drawing" in google and found this...

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time in most accents, these words should be distinct.

---

### Vowels

First of all, the vowels are different. *Drawing* contains the /ɔː/ followed by /ɪ/, while *join* contains the diphthong /ɔɪ/:

- /ɔɪ/ is a **diphthong**, a single vowel sound that changes from one place of articulation to another gradually.  It cannot be pronounced as two separate sounds.
- /ɔː/ and /ɪ/ are **monophthongs**, each single vowel sounds which do not change noticeably in place of articulation over time.  Although there is often a smooth transition from one to the other, you can pronounce *draw* and *ing* separately; you can't do the same with *join*.  And because /ɔː/ and /ɪ/ are separate vowel sounds, in non-rhotic varieties of English, /r/ may be inserted in between (*draw**r**ing*) to separate them; this cannot happen with *join*.

Even though we write the diphthong /ɔɪ/ with the same two phonetic symbols, that doesn't mean that it's pronounced in the same way as a sequence of those two vowel sounds:

- In American English, /ɔː/ is likely to be a backer vowel than the start of /ɔɪ/.
- In both American and British English, /ɪ/ is likely to be fronter and higher than the end of /ɔɪ/.
- And of course, /ɔː/ in *draw* is a long vowel.

And in some American English accents, /ɑː/ is used instead of /ɔː/, making the words more distinct.

---

### Consonants

Since /r/ may be somewhat palatalized in *drawing*, it may trigger a phenomenon called **yod coalescence**, where /d/ becomes the affricate /dʒ/, the same sound that's in *join*.  If you hear the non-affricate /d/ it's *join* rather than *drawing*, but if you hear the affricate it could be either word.  In that case, the following /r/ should help you distinguish them, but it might be difficult to hear the difference some of the time.

In careful speech, the final /n/ in *join* is different from the /ŋ/ in *drawing*, but in casual speech /ŋ/ may become /n/, and in connected speech the nasal may assimilate to other places of articulation (for example to /m/ in *drawin' boats*).  So outside of careful speech, these may be distinguishable some of the time, but not all of the time.

---

### Context

When we listen to words, we almost never hear them in isolation.  They almost always come in a linguistic context with other words, and these words carry meaning.  We automatically use this meaning to determine which words are possible or likely:

> Carol's ＿＿＿ a picture.

If you heard someone say this sentence, but you couldn't hear the word I've blanked out at all, would you be able to guess whether the speaker meant to say *drawing* or *join*?  Only one of the two words makes sense.

In fact, it's rare that both *drawing* and *join* will make sense in a sentence.  Even if the words sound very similar (which is possible sometimes in some accents in non-careful, connected speech), you can still use context to tell which of the words was intended.